# Does RoboSpice's getFromCache() take that long?

Tags: java, android, robospice

I'm trying to use *RoboSpice* + *Retrofit* + *Jackson* in an app. When I open an activity, I want to check if a resource is already cached, and if it is, simply update the view, otherwise, make a new request and wait for the answer. All of this is working ok, but I noticed that the `getFromCache()` method takes a lot of time.

I implemented the cache with a LRUCache (by decorating the default Retrofit persister), as follows:

```
@Override
public <T> ObjectPersister<T> createObjectPersister(Class<T> clazz) throws CacheCreationException {
    try {
        return new LruCacheObjectPersister<T>(new RetrofitObjectPersister<T>(getApplication(), converter, clazz), new LruCache<Object, CacheItem<T>>(20)); // TODO: Set a max size
    } catch (CacheCreationException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not create cache for class '" + clazz.getName() + "'", e);
    }
}
```

As I said, the caches are working ok, I debugged everything and the LRUCache is being used as expected, as well as the `RetrofitObjectPersister` which in fact is a disk cache.

That being said, my question is:

**Is it normal that the `getFromCache()` method takes a noticeable time even if the object is in the memory cache? I understand that it should be noticeable for objects that are retrieved from the disk cache, but I cannot understand why it takes that long to get the object from memory? Does it have to do with the *RoboSpice*'s service architecture, perhaps?**

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you very much,

mato

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by taking a lot of time ?  Can you give numbers (maybe comparing the numbers with your cache decorator and without it) ?

It's possible that their is an overhead due to the design of RS that always executes async code from inside an Android service. Basically the round trip to get something in the cache is :

```
SpiceManager -> SpiceService -> ExecutorService -> Thread -> CacheManager
             <-              <-                 <-        <-
```

This is a little costly for sure, but that the design of RS. Usually the overhead is just of a few ms.

Comment: It's about half a second. In my use case, I just want to get the data from the cache in the Activity´s `onCreate` method and display right away to the user. But it takes that time to refresh the screen, which in my opinion it's a lot of time if the data is already in memory.
I agree with you @Snicolas, it seems to be related with RS architecture on services. Don't get it wrong, I love the architecture, and I think it's the correct approach to deal with the Activities lifecycle, but I think that if I use memory cache, I should get the result immediately. What do you think about it?

Comment: I agree with you, it should be faster for sure. Nevertheless, I can't get a clear idea of what happens and how slow RS is in that particular case. What is the difference in time between the memory vs disk cache ? If there is a big difference then your cache implementation is the culprit, maybe you have a slow equal function, something like this. If both are slow, then RS owns the guilt. Then which device/emulator do you use, and is that as slow on a second call, when the service is already started ?

Comment: Disk cache is taking almost a second to get the objects, while memory cache takes the half. This makes sense. I did not implement a cache, as I'm using the LRUCache. I'm running my app in Genymotion. And regarding your last question, the first call take longer because it needs to fetch the data from Internet, while the later ones only need to go to the cache (either memory or disk) to get the data. Thanks!

Comment: I see. Thx for the details. Do you have any idea of where the bottleneck is and what we could change to boost performances ?

Comment: I think the bottleneck is in the Service architecture. I didn't dig too much in the RS code, but I think this is because of the requests queue. It takes a little time to get a request from the queue and process it. And that's ok, that's whats make the request independent to the activities lifecycle. But I think that if someone wants to use an in-memory cache, it shouldn't be processed in the Service, but in the RS managers, so that the queue processing is not involved in the process and RS can respond right away with the objects in the cache. How does this sound to you? Thanks!

Comment: Interesting...Quite interesting. It might even be a track to enhance RS performances for all cache work. Would you feel an issue for this in our github issue board, I would mark it as 1.5.0 desired feature. This might take some time to be included as this involves quite a lot of refactoring. Let's see if that could be elegantly implemented. And please refer to our thread here.
Tough I would like to emphasize that on a Nexus 4, my dev phone, processing a request with wifi generally lies around 150 ms for a good server !

Comment: I really wonder what the gain would be. Would you mind to write a custom spice manager and see if there is a real gain to bypass the service for getting cached data ? Hack it, just to see if there would be again, you could completely cut through request processing and return what a cache manager local the spice manager would return. (Moreover that is also something RS allows to do : use a cache manager without service, though it didn't seem to attract anyone up to now)

Comment: I'm quite busy in my work right now (and switched to iOS development) and I cannot work on this. But it's crystal clear to me; if the objects were retrieved from the in-memory cache without having to do the service roundtrip, it'd be blazing fast, enough to make it imperceptible in the UI.

As soon as I get my current work done, I'll try to put some effort on this, but I cannot promise any date.

Thanks for your help!